# Disable Create Button for expired Dates in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How can enable/disable a button in Angular if the endDate is less than currentDate.
For example:
enddate: 01.02.2021
currentdate: 01.02.2022
=> Button to create an new entry will be disabled.

---

**my HTML**

```
<a class="btn btn-link" [ngClass]="{ 'disabled': !contract.availableLicenseCount && contract.contractEndDate < currentDate}" (click)="contract.availableLicenseCount && createNewLicense(contract)" >
  <i [c8yIcon]="'plus-circle'"></i> {{ 'New Licence' }}
</a>
```

**my component**

```
export class AllLicensesComponent implements OnInit {
  public contracts: Contract[] = [];
  endDate = new Date(contracts.contractEndDate);
  currentDate = new Date('2023-02-01');
}
```

**my Model**

```
export class Contract {
  contractEndDate: Date;

  constructor(contract?: Partial<Contract>) {
    this.contractEndDate = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: @GRD Could you please tell me how can I call data for enddate? `import { Contract } from '@src/models/contract'; ` 
`public contracts: Contract[] = [];` 
`endDate: Date = Contract.contractEndDate;` 
  `export class Contract ` 
`{ contractEndDate: Date;`
 `constructor(contract?: Partial<Contract>) { this.contractEndDate = null; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compare dates with `>` operator. We use `[disable]` to evaluate prop `isDisabled` to disable or enable the button.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  isDisabled: boolean = false;
  endDate: Date = new Date('Febuary 02, 2021 23:15:30');
  today: Date = new Date;
  constructor() {
    if (this.endDate < this.today) {
      this.isDisabled = true;
    }
   }
}
```

```html
<button mat-stroked-button 
        color="primary" 
        class="common-button">Button
</button>
<button mat-stroked-button 
        color="primary"
        [disabled]="isDisabled"
        class="common-button">Button disabled
</button>

endDate: {{endDate}}
today: {{today}}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-button-molyas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts